# Getting err_tunnel_connection_failed and err_connection_timed_out when accessing URL

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, http, wifi, 502-error

My company has deployed an SSO solution using Duende Identity Server and Okta

We are using a proxy as the middleman between Identity Server and Okta:

https://apacwelcome.saas.mrisoftware.com

99% of customers have no issues connecting to the proxy, however we have had a few who are getting either `err_tunnel_connection_failed` or `err_connection_timed_out`.

We have got the users to try everything we have found on Google, but nothing works. eg Incognito mode, different browser, reset computer, use a different computer, and these commands:

```
ipconfig /flushdns

ipconfig /release

ipconfig /renew

netsh int ip set dns

netsh winsock reset
```

This only happens when they're on their office wifi. If they switch to their cell phone hotspot, use their home wifi, or a VPN, it works fine.

They have confirmed with their IT department that the URLs are not being blocked.

Here you can see the 502 returned:

[image]

However, once the company's VPN is used, it works fine:

[image]

We have had users also report that it was originally working, and then one day it stopped and they consistently get `err_connection_timed_out` from now on.

Does anyone know why this is happening to some users?

Can there be some settings in office wifi setups that would prevent that site from being reached?

The IT department is sure there is nothing set up on the network to block that URL.